# How to solve TypeError: cells.editable is not a function in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I m using the following jquery files in my file and the order is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascirpt" src="jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.editable.js"></script>
```

and the  versions are

jquery-1.10.2.min.js

jQuery UI - v1.10.4

DataTables 1.10.2

jquery.jeditable.js Version 1.6.2

jquery.dataTables.editable.js Version:     2.3.3.

when i run my html file i get this error  "TypeError: cells.editable is not a function" in jquery.dataTables.editable.js  in line 388
and the line is

```
   cells.editable(properties.sUpdateURL, $.extend({}, oDefaultEditableSettings, 
   properties.oEditableSettings));
```

Why Datatables troubling this much.? Can anyone help

Comment: `</script`   closing tag missing at last line.. :)

Comment: @@Jitendra Yadav: I closed it.